# How to distribute points on valleys only?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes, vector

I want to add vegetation to my rocky semi-desert scene of Himalayan mountains, using geometry nodes. In that scenery, vegetation only grows in valleys, where water would sometimes flow.
Note that by valleys I also mean slopes between hills and flat surfaces in various heights, surrounded by mountains.

The OPPOSITE of the tree distribution in this picture:
[image]

How do I do that procedurally, meaning without weight painting the valleys by hand?
I tried to find some vector math trick, but failed to do so. Please help!